# Please help me visualize popd and pushd

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I'm working through The Command Line Crash Course. I've been doing really well, but now find myself completely stumped at popd and pushd. I've read the analogy of a stack of plates or pancakes. I still don't get it, because I cannot visualize the code that comes after. For example:

pats-MacBook-Pro:temp pat$ pushd i/like/icecream

~/temp/i/like/icecream ~/temp

If pushd is like cd, then why does the second line show ~/temp at the end of the line? How does that part fit into the 'stack of plates' analogy?

Then if I type popd, it takes me back to the original folder, ~/temp. Why?

I really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: I get it!!! I finally flipping get it! Thank you Jasper and garyjohn! dirs -v really, really helps! Thanks again, so much! I was starting to lose my marbles!

Answer (score 2):

`pushd` can take one argument (a directory name), stores the current directory on the `DIRSTACK` and changes the current working directory to the given directory. The manpage further explains:

> If  the  pushd  command  is  successful, a `dirs` is performed as well.

And `dirs` prints the currently remembered directories. `popd`'s purpose is to pop (remove from stack) the "uppermost" remembered directory and `cd` into the new "uppermost" remembered directory. After a successful `popd`, again a `dirs` command is executed to print the current stack. If you do `dirs` in a fresh shell, you will see that the current workind directory is always contained in the `DIRSTACK` variable -- this is where your ~/temp comes from.

An example: assume we have directories `one`, `one/two` and `three` in our home directory:

```
~ $ pushd one   # change into one, remember current location
~/one ~
~/one $ pushd two   # change into two, remember current location
~/one/two ~/one ~   
~/one/two $ cd ../../three  # change into three, don't remember where we came from
~/three $ dirs  # show where we are and where we can get back to
~/three ~/one ~
~/three $ popd  # go back one step in the remembered directories
~/one ~
~/one $
```

You can think of the `pushd`/`popd` commands as a way to do "change into this directory, but remember where we came from (`pushd`); do things in the new directory; change directory back (`popd`). This will also get clearer if you do multiple `pushd`s in a row without `popd`ing. Then the "stack of plates" analogy should become obvious.

Answer (score 1):

In order to conserve vertical space on the screen, `pushd` is showing you the stack horizontally, with new items being pushed from the left.

You started with one item on the stack, the working directory, ~/temp. When you executed `pushd i/like/icecream`, `pushd` pushed i/like/icecream onto the top of the stack, pushing ~/temp down. The way that `pushd` displayed the result, though, was to show that i/like/icecream had been pushed onto the stack from the left, moving ~/temp to the right. `pushd` also changes the working directory to the directory just pushed onto the stack, which was i/like/icecream.

`popd` pops the stack, removing the top item (i/like/icecream) and letting the next item (~/temp) pop to the top of the stack, becoming the new working directory.

`popd`, like `pushd`, shows the stack on its side, with the top of the stack on the left and the bottom of the stack on the right.

It might help you to visualize the current state of the stack with the `dirs -v` command, which displays the stack vertically.

Answer (score 1):

I found popd difficult at the beginning, too, but the following helped me:

for **bash**, basically: instead of using `cd` you can use `pushd` to change directorys, so they are stacked or to say it in other words: the history of changed directorys is saved.

```
pushd /home; pushd /var; pushd log
```

To see the stack (or history) use `dirs` and for easier navigation (to get the numbers of the "stack-entrys" use:

```
dirs -v
```

Output:

```
me@myhost:/home$ dirs -v
 0  /home
 1  /var
 2  /tmp
```

Now **utilize these numbers with `cd` and `~`** like:

```
cd ~1
```

... so you can navigate the "history" of directorys (meaning navigation in the stack)

But now these numbers are rearranged now and position "0" will change, so just `pushd` the directory to the top position twice (or use a dummy on position 0) like:

```
me@myhost:/home$ dirs -v
 0  /home
 1  /home
 2  /var
 3  /tmp
```

now 1..3 will keep there position
*I read this somewhere but do not know anymore, so sorry for not giving credit*

(to release the current directory from the stack/deleting it from history use `popd`)